# error: "gets" not declare in thi cope on codeblock 10.0

Tags: c++, gets

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class student
    {
    private:
        int admno;
        char sname[20];
        float eng,math,science;
        float total;
        float ctotal()
        {
            return eng+math+science;
        }
    public:
        void Takedata()
        {
            cout<<"Enter admission number ";
            cin>> admno;
            cout<<"Enter student name " ;
            gets(sname);// here its giving the error
            cout<< "Enter marks in english, math, science ";
            cin>>eng>>math>>science;
            total=ctotal();
        };

    void Showdata()
    {
        cout<<"Admission number "<<admno<<"\nStudent name "<<sname<<"\nEnglish "
            <<eng<<"\nMath "<<math<<"\nScience "<<science<<"\nTotal "<<total;
    }
};
int main ()
{
    student obj ;
    obj.Takedata();
    obj.Showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to use gets in a c++ program, thats what cin is for

Comment: `gets` is not declared in `iostream` (it is/was a C function) and is obsolete, as far as I know. Even if it's available in your library, you should never use it. Use C++ I/O in C++.

Comment: and use std::string not char[20]

Comment: plz modify the program for me someone. i reqquest

Comment: [tag:gets] was already deprecated. Did you hover or click your mouse into the tag and read its description? [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Answer (score 1):

use `std::cin.getline` instead of `gets` and `std::string` instead of `char []`.

As comments pointed out, `gets` is not declared in `iostream`. Furthermore, it has been deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++14, which means even if you include `cstdio` or `stdio.h`, it just do not compile in compilers supporting C++14.

But still, never use `std::cin` for `char []`. The reason is the same as `gets`. Both will make your program under the danger of **buffer overflow** when your input is longer than buffer, which will cause your program has unexpected behaviour, like crash. And crackers may even hack your whole computer with it.